# How to send Buffers to DAL Plugin from an application

Tags: swift, macos, c++11

I have been trying to find an answer since a week now. I have compiled and copied the DAL plugin to /Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL but simply cannot find a way I can send the buffer to the plugin from an application that will let user selct an image that can be sent to plugin.(swift or C++). this is the plugin I am using https://github.com/seanchas116/SimpleDALPlugin

I have tried to call the Plugin methods from a swift application. But so far unable to call the PluginInterface API.

I have asked questions to every DAL Plugin repository but no answer so far.